# How to read magnetic card data?

Tags: encode, magnetic-cards

I work with the magnetic card reader "MiniMag II" (ref. IDMB-334133B and datasheet [here](http://www.idtechproducts.com/index.php/download/doc_download/360-minimag-ii-datasheet.html)) on Windows 7. A driver has ben automatically installed, adding the card reader as a standard input device to Windows recognized devices.
When I swipe a card in the reader, card data is sent to the pc and written in the current window.
My problem concerns the card data format : I receive strings such as "*méà(è&('&_é"(à&&à=àààààààààààààààààààà§*", do you recognize a format here ?
I am not aware of the exact data format, but I know that the following numbers are included in their corresponding card data :

- 412835  : méà(è&'&é_"(à"&é-=&çà"'àçà(&àààààààààà§
- 418559  : méà(è&'&_((çà'&&-=&(&à'&'&à&àààààààààà§
- 2989449 : méà(è&éç_ç''çà&&à=àààààààààààààààààààà§
- 5418235 : méà(è&('&_é"(à&&à=àààààààààààààààààààà§

Do you have any lead to help me to understand how the received card data is built ?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean " as a standard input device" ? Normally, Mag Readers are serially attached. Is our one USB or Serial? It sounds like your device driver is acting as a keyboard...

Comment: OK, I've just read the data sheet. The device supports many interface options. How are you connecting it to your PC?

Comment: I use the default configuration with the automatically downloaded driver, which is the USB keyboard interface I guess, as it appears as a keyboard in Windows devices. The reader is USB connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, my system was in AZERTY mode and the reader input me QWERTY data... so when I changed the settings I have obtained the numbers I was looking for. Hope it can help someone.

Comment: Any chance that you found a way to have it working without changing computer locale ? superuser.com/questions/1016295